# Pin tabs in a tab panel

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4

i couldn't find a better title,
but i would like to build a tab panel with two tabs that are always present
and a undefined number of other tabs that are generated dynamically by the user.

I would like to implement something similar to the app-Tabs in Firefox:

The tabs added by the user should be scrollable, while the other 2 tabs should be pinned and always displayed.

Here's an image:
[image]

Is this possible via ext or do I have to do it via css?

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok for those who are interested, here is how i did it now.

I shift my tab bar to the right by applying a padding-left.
The two tabs that i want to pin are hidden
and in the free space that results from the padding i put two buttons and make them look like tabs.

If they are clicked, the hidden buttons are activated.

It's not completely finished, but i think it will act as desired.

Comment: Good idea. You could also create a 1-row, 2-column table layout, or any other valid horizontal arrangement of two containers, and place a separate tabBar in each.